# How to prepopulate date field based on other date field?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have 2 date fields in oracle apex, Date1 is mandatory needs to be input by user and Date2 needs to prepopulate as (Date1+2 years) then user clicks the save button to save the values in database.
Then, if user clicks Date2 and change to something else, it should take that value and save.

Eg:
1.User inputs Date1 - 02/07/2019
2.Date2 should automatically populate as - 02/07/2021 but should not be saved in database.
3.User clicks save button to save data.
4.User wants to change Date2 to - 05/10/2019
5.User clicks save to save data.

I tried to set value using dynamic action for step2, but step4 is not working whenever I click save button, it's recalculating back to Date1+2 years.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have P1_ID (primary key), P1_DATE1 and P1_DATE2 on your form.

1. Create a dynamic action to set value of P1_DATE2 on change of P1_DATE1. Use PL/SQL Expression as type and PL/SQL Expression
   `ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P1_DATE1,'DD/MM/YYYY'),24);`
2. Set "Fire on initialization" to false so it won't recalculate P1_DATE2 when the screen loads for an existing record - that might be the cause of the behaviour you're seeing.
3. It makes sense that you only want the dynamic action to fire for a new record so you could add a server-side condition in your dynamic action of "ITEM IS NULL" for item P1_ID.

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I need to do the validations for the dates, so I have a process which is on submit - after validations to update the dates in database, and so I don't want to set the value into database using dynamic action. Any advise?

Comment: Have you tried it out yourself ? The dynamic actions do not affect your submit process. They are just setting the values in the session (as if you would change it). The validation will happen on the values that are set by the dynamic actions.

Comment: Thanks Koen, The solution is working fine, but in Apex 5.1 after selecting date in the date picker, it's taking min 10 sec to show the value in the field. Is there anyway we can get the date in  the field instantly.

Comment: No sorry I don't have a 5.1 install to test on.